# android device information with python script

Tags: android, python, sl4a

Good day!
How can i get device information from norooted device with python script? As I understand python don't have API like os.android.build in Java.

I need to get system information from device, such as cpu frequencies, gpu vendor and other (like in Antutu and another benchmarks). 
I know how to write python script with $getprop information from shell, and from buil.prop file in the system files, but it isn't enough. I also know how to get these information with shell command and busybox installed, but I shouldn't root them/

Any advice? Thank you

Comment: I can't help you, but I love the way you start your question with 'Good day!'... awesome :)